# For loop to compare one element with all the remaining elements of an array

Tags: python, arrays, for-loop

I have an array in Python `[0,1,2,3,4]` with 5 elements. I want to compare elements in following fashion.

```
(0,1),(0,2),(0,3),(0,4),(1,2),(1,3),(1,4),(2,3),(2,4),(3,4),(4,4)
```

What I am doing is as follows.

```
for i in range(len(array)):
   for j in range(i+1,len(array)):
```

But this is comparing in following fashion.

```
(0,1),(1,2),(2,3),(3,4)...
```

Where I am doing it wrong?

Comment: Do you want the result, or do you want to write it yourself?

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 I want logic if I want to compare elements in above fashion.

Comment: With a line of `print(array[i], array[j])` after those loops, I get the desired output (except for `(4, 4)`, which isn't actually part of a combinations sequence).

Comment: Your nested `for` loops look correct, so if they aren't giving you the element pairs you expect there must be something else wrong with your code. Try to create a [mcve] that illustrates this problem.

Comment: Why you have `(4,4)` at the end of your expected output?

Answer (score -1):

This code produces the desired result:

```
array = [0,1,2,3,4]
for i in range(len(array)):
    for j in range(i+1,len(array)):
        print(array[i], array[j])
print(array[-1], array[-1])
```

This code is one way that you may have gotten the erroneous result:

```
for i in range(len(array)):
    for j in range(i+1,len(array)):
        print(array[i], array[j])
        break
```

Comment: Why would there be a `break` in there? Anything's _possible_, but what do you base this guess on?

Comment: @TigerhawkT3: It is a simple change that produced the reported results.  It's just a guess, but it was the only way I could think of without making things a lot more complicated.

Answer (score -1):

Using itertools is another option:

```
>>> [x for x in itertools.combinations(xrange(5), 2)]
[(0, 1), (0, 2), (0, 3), (0, 4), (1, 2), (1, 3), (1, 4), (2, 3), (2, 4), (3, 4)]
```

Comment: Do you have an explanation for why the OP's code doesn't work for them?

Comment: @TigerhawkT3, no, since his code is not complete (the for loops looks ok), also comparing each element with himself (I mean the (4,4)) is a stupid thing since you know it will always be true, or that they will always be there.